# Intersection of two exponential functions (of different bases)

Tags: calculus

What is the point of intersection (x,y) of the two functions $y=x^{1/2}$ and $y=e^{-3x}$? (This is for a volume of a solid of revolution problem.)

Comment: This is not a trivial problem... Are you sure that the equations given are the correct ones?  One could approximate a solution using things like newton's or picard's methods, but it doesn't appear to have a closed exact form.  It will be at $x\approx 0.238734129...$ and appropriate $y$

Comment: Rearranging the problem yields $\ln x + 6x = 0$. However, it isn't possible to get anything more trivial than that. Approximate methods such as Newton's method would have to be used to approximate the intersection point.

Comment: These are the equations. Maybe I'm approaching the problem wrong? The original problem is "Let R be the shaded region bounded by the graphs of $y=x^{1/2}$, $y=e^{-3x}$, and $x=1$. Find the volume of the solid generated when R is revolved about the horizontal line $y=1$." I obtained the indefinite integral for the volume, but was stuck with this problem (I.E., where to start the definite integration. The end is at $x=1$, meaning 1).

Comment: @shman613 regardless of the process that you use to approach the problem, you still need to calculate the intersections point between the two functions

Comment: These are not *two* exponential functions, only one of them is

Answer (score 1):

Equate right hand sides (with one squaring) solve numerically.

$$ x \, e^{6 x } = 1 \Rightarrow  x \approx 0.2387 $$

Comment: (See my comment on the original question). So is there no way to get an expression representing where to start the definite integral?

Comment: If you are rotating with resp to x-axis $V = \int \pi y^2 dx ;$ now   $ y \rightarrow ( 1-y) $

Answer (score 1):

The graph below shows it is not some simple solution:

[image: Graph]

The tiny font says $A=(0.24,0.49)$ with the rounded coordinates of the intersection point.

Building on Narasimham's answer, one might try the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) here,
on
$$
6 = 6x \, e^{6x} = f(6x) \Rightarrow \\
W(6) = W(f(6x)) = 6x \Rightarrow \\
x = W(6)/6
$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve
$$\sqrt{x}=e^{-3x};$$
for $x$. Divide both sides by $e^{-3x}$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{-3x}}=1;$$
rewrite $\sqrt{x}/e^{-3x}=\sqrt{x}e^{3x}$:
$$\sqrt{x}e^{3x}=1;$$
square both sides:
$$xe^{6x}=1;$$
multiply both sides by $6$:
$$6xe^{6x}=6;$$
substitute $u=6x$:
$$ue^u=6;$$
take the product logarithms of both sides:
$$u=\operatorname{W}_k(6);$$
substitute back for $u$:
$$6x=\operatorname{W}_k(6);$$
divide both sides by $6$:
$$x=\frac{\operatorname{W}_k(6)}{6};$$
write out the answer:
$$\therefore x=\boxed{\frac{\operatorname{W}_k(6)}{6}}\phantom{.},$$
where $\operatorname{W}_k$ is the $k$-th branch of the product log function.

The solution is real for $k=0$:
$$x\in\mathbb{R}\implies x=\frac{\operatorname{W}_0(6)}{6}=\frac{\operatorname{W}(6)}{6}\approx0.2387341293163833852.$$